# How to set the subplot axis range

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, subplot

How can I set the y axis range of the second subplot to e.g. [0,1000] ?
The FFT plot of my data (a column in a text file) results in a (inf.?) spike so that the actual data is not visible.

```py
pylab.ylim([0,1000])
```

has no effect, unfortunately. This is the whole script:

```py
# based on http://www.swharden.com/blog/2009-01-21-signal-filtering-with-python/
import numpy, scipy, pylab, random

xs = []
rawsignal = []
with open("test.dat", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] != '#' and len(line) > 0:
            xs.append( int( line.split()[0] ) )
            rawsignal.append( int( line.split()[1] ) )

h, w = 3, 1
pylab.figure(figsize=(12,9))
pylab.subplots_adjust(hspace=.7)

pylab.subplot(h,w,1)
pylab.title("Signal")
pylab.plot(xs,rawsignal)

pylab.subplot(h,w,2)
pylab.title("FFT")
fft = scipy.fft(rawsignal)
#~ pylab.axis([None,None,0,1000])
pylab.ylim([0,1000])
pylab.plot(abs(fft))

pylab.savefig("SIG.png",dpi=200)
pylab.show()
```

Other improvements are also appreciated!

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858192/how-to-set-xlim-and-ylim-for-a-subplot-in-matplotlib/15858264?noredirect=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting y-axis limit in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777861/setting-y-axis-limit-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 301):

You have [`pylab.ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html):

```
pylab.ylim([0,1000])
```

Note: The command has to be executed after the plot!

**Update 2021**
Since [the use of pylab is now strongly discouraged by matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html?highlight=pylab#module-pylab), you should instead use pyplot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ylim(0, 100) 
#corresponding function for the x-axis
plt.xlim(1, 1000)
```

Comment: Whenever I do this, it flips the images upside down.

Comment: if i use this with hexbin, uses ylim after plot() exposes white background on both plots

Comment: WHat if you are not using plot, but savefig??

Comment: Call `plot()`, then `ylim()` and then `savefig()`.

Comment: in subplots it's `set_ylim()`.

Answer (score 119):

Using [axes objects](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) is a great approach for this. It helps if you want to interact with multiple figures and sub-plots. To add and manipulate the axes objects directly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))

signal_axes = fig.add_subplot(211)
signal_axes.plot(xs,rawsignal)

fft_axes = fig.add_subplot(212)
fft_axes.set_title("FFT")
fft_axes.set_autoscaley_on(False)
fft_axes.set_ylim([0,1000])
fft = scipy.fft(rawsignal)
fft_axes.plot(abs(fft))

plt.show()
```

Comment: As Rob suggests, the OO interface in matplotlib is preferred over the state-based pylab interface. "Although many examples use pylab, it is no longer recommended. For non-interactive plotting it is suggested to use pyplot to create the figures and then the OO interface for plotting." https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related

Answer (score 28):

Sometimes you really want to set the axes limits *before* you plot the data.  In that case, you can set the "autoscaling" feature of the `Axes` or `AxesSubplot` object.  The functions of interest are `set_autoscale_on`, `set_autoscalex_on`, and `set_autoscaley_on`.

In your case, you want to freeze the y axis' limits, but allow the x axis to expand to accommodate your data.  Therefore, you want to change the `autoscaley_on` property to `False`.  Here is a modified version of the FFT subplot snippet from your code:

```
fft_axes = pylab.subplot(h,w,2)
pylab.title("FFT")
fft = scipy.fft(rawsignal)
pylab.ylim([0,1000])
fft_axes.set_autoscaley_on(False)
pylab.plot(abs(fft))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple subplots, i.e.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 2)
```

You can use the same y limits for all of them. It gets limits of y ax from first plot.

```
plt.setp(ax, ylim=ax[0,0].get_ylim())
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to set `ylim`/`xlim` at the time of adding a subplot to the existing figure instance (`plt.subplot` admits `ylim=` argument).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.arange(1000)                             # sample data
rawsignal = np.random.rand(1000)
fft = np.fft.fft(rawsignal)

plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))                        # create figure
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1, title='Signal')             # first subplot
plt.plot(xs, rawsignal)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2, title='FFT', ylim=(0,100))  # second subplot
#                                 ^^^^^  <---- set ylim here
plt.plot(abs(fft));
```

Then again, using the object-oriented interface is less verbose and clearer. Axes instances define `set()` method which can be used to set a whole host of properties including y-limit/title etc.

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(9,6))
ax1.plot(xs, rawsignal)                # plot rawsignal in the first Axes
ax1.set(title='Signal')                # set the title of the first Axes
ax2.plot(abs(fft))                     # plot FFT in the second Axes
ax2.set(ylim=(0, 100), title='FFT');   # set title and y-limit of the second Axes
```

Both sets of codes produce the same following output.

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact axis you want, then

`pylab.ylim([0,1000])`

works as answered previously. But if you want a more flexible axis to fit your exact data, as I did when I found this question, then set axis limit to be the length of your dataset. If your dataset is `fft` as in the question, then add this after your plot command:

`length = (len(fft))
pylab.ylim([0,length])`