# How to set the axis limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis, x-axis

I need help with setting the limits of y-axis on matplotlib. Here is the code that I tried, unsuccessfully.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1, figsize = (8.5,11))
plt.suptitle('plot title')
ax = []
aPlot = plt.subplot(321, axisbg = 'w', title = "Year 1")
ax.append(aPlot)
plt.plot(paramValues,plotDataPrice[0], color = '#340B8C', 
     marker = 'o', ms = 5, mfc = '#EB1717')
plt.xticks(paramValues)
plt.ylabel('Average Price')
plt.xlabel('Mark-up')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim((25,250))
```

With the data I have for this plot, I get y-axis limits of 20 and 200. However, I want the limits to be 20 and 250.

Answer (score 971):

Get current axis via `plt.gca()`, and then set its limits:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
```

Comment: BTW, this is a silly abbreviation means "**g**et the **c**urrent **a**xes".

Comment: you can also set one value `None` which leaves the calculation to matplotlib, e.g. `axes.set_ylim([ymin,None])`

Comment: There are other options instead of using `None` as in @linqu 's post: `set_ylim(bottom=None, top=None, [...], *, ymin=None, ymax=None)`. `bottom` and `ymin` (equivalent) for minimum. `top` and `ymax`) equivalent for maximum. You can't use both `bottom` and `ymin` at once. Same with `top` and `ymax`.

Answer (score 187):

One thing you can do is to set your axis range by yourself by using matplotlib.pyplot.axis.

**matplotlib.pyplot.axis**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 20])
```

0,10 is for x axis range.
0,20 is for y axis range.

or you can also use matplotlib.pyplot.xlim or matplotlib.pyplot.ylim

**matplotlib.pyplot.ylim**

```
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.xlim(0,10)
```

Comment: You can also fix only one of axis like: `plt.ylim(-2, None)`, `plt.xlim(None, 10)`

Answer (score 154):

Another workaround is to get the plot's axes and reassign changing only the y-values:

```
x1,x2,y1,y2 = plt.axis()  
plt.axis((x1,x2,25,250))
```

Comment: You don't need to grab `x1` and `x2`, you can have matplotlib infer these with `None`.

Answer (score 44):

You can instantiate an object from `matplotlib.pyplot.axes` and call the `set_ylim()` on it. It would be something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
axes = plt.axes()
axes.set_ylim([0, 1])
```

Answer (score 43):

Just for fine tuning. If you want to set only one of the boundaries of the axis and let the other boundary unchanged, you can choose one or more of the following statements

```
plt.xlim(right=xmax) #xmax is your value
plt.xlim(left=xmin) #xmin is your value
plt.ylim(top=ymax) #ymax is your value
plt.ylim(bottom=ymin) #ymin is your value
```

Take a look at the documentation for [xlim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) and for [ylim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html)

Answer (score 30):

This worked at least in matplotlib version 2.2.2:

```
plt.axis([None, None, 0, 100])
```

Probably this is a nice way to set up for example xmin and ymax only, etc.

Answer (score 18):

To add to @Hima's answer, if you want to modify a current x or y limit you could use the following.

```
import numpy as np # you probably alredy do this so no extra overhead
fig, axes = plt.subplot()
axes.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
xlim = axes.get_xlim()
# example of how to zoomout by a factor of 0.1
factor = 0.1 
new_xlim = (xlim[0] + xlim[1])/2 + np.array((-0.5, 0.5)) * (xlim[1] - xlim[0]) * (1 + factor) 
axes.set_xlim(new_xlim)
```

I find this particularly useful when I want to zoom out or zoom in just a little from the default plot settings.

Answer (score 12):

This should work.  Your code works for me, like for Tamás and Manoj Govindan.  It looks like you could try to update Matplotlib.  If you can't update Matplotlib (for instance if you have insufficient administrative rights), maybe using a different backend with `matplotlib.use()` could help.

Comment: Thanks for checking! I am using the pdf backend (`matplotlib.use('PDF')`). I am using the version that comes with latest version of the Enthought Python Distribution. Can you please see if it works with the PDF backend. Thanks!

Comment: It does work with the PDF backend, on Mac OS X.  Are you sure that the output file is indeed updated with `plt.savefig()`?

Comment: I realized the problem, I think. If I take out `aPlot =` in the `plt.subplot` line it works for me too. It seems that if one assigns the subplot to a variable like that, some other method of setting the axes limits must be used. Is that true?

Comment: As far as I know, `plt.ylim()` applies the limits to the current axes, which are set when you do `plt.subplot()`.  I also can't believe that `plt.subplot()` care about how the axes it returns are used (put into a variable or not, etc.).  So I'd say it should work; it does work on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

`ylim` can be set using `Axes.set()`. In fact a whole host of properties can be set via `set()`, such as ticks, ticklabels, labels, title etc. (that were set separately in the OP).

```py
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set(ylim=(20, 250), xlim=(0, 100))
```

Then again, `ylim` (and other properties) can be set in the `plt.subplot` instance as well. For the case in the OP, that would be

```py
aPlot = plt.subplot(321, facecolor='w', title="Year 1", ylim=(20,250), xticks=paramValues, ylabel='Average Price', xlabel='Mark-up')
#                                                       ^^^^  <---- ylim here
plt.plot(paramValues, plotDataPrice[0], color='#340B8C', marker='o', ms=5, mfc='#EB1717');
```

To set `ylim` (and other properties) for multiple subplots, use `plt.setp`. For example, if we include 2 more subplots to OP's code and if we want to set the same properties to all of them, one way to do it would be as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

plt.figure(1, figsize = (8.5,11))
plt.suptitle('plot title')
ax = []
paramValues = range(10)
for i in range(1, 4):
    aPlot = plt.subplot(3,2,i, title=f"Year {i}")
    ax.append(aPlot)
    aPlot.plot(paramValues, [random.randint(20,200) for _ in paramValues], color='#340B8C', marker='o', ms=5, mfc='#EB1717')
    aPlot.grid(True);

plt.setp(ax, ylim=(20,250), facecolor='w', xticks=paramValues, ylabel='Average Price', xlabel='Mark-up')
#            ^^^^  <---- ylim here
plt.tight_layout();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()` .

Check out the code below to understand it properly.

```
x = np.array([1,2,5,4,8])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

plt.plot(x,x**2, label='Square', marker='*')
plt.plot(x,x**3, label='Cube', marker='o')
plt.xlim(1,20)
plt.ylim(1,600)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Output is shown in the photo below.**

[image: Output]

Comment: This has been flagged to a moderator as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/49706791/7758804, which already covers `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim`.