# How to set y-axis for historgram in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

According to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim), one can set the range of the x-axis using the `hist` function, but there doesn't seem to be a way to control the y-axis.

I have a figure with 4 subplots, arranged in a 2x2 fashion, all of which are histograms. I have made their x-axis to be entirely the same by setting the `range`, but have been unable to figure out how to do likewise with the y-axis. But when I try to control the y-axis, using `set_ylim`, I get an error. When I tried using `pylab.axis`, the plots didn't turn out correctly (the bars of the historgram all had a y-value of 0.

```
pylab.hist(myData[x], bins = 20, range=(0,400))
pylab.axis([0,400,0,300])
```

How do I control the y-axis of the histogram? Essentially what I"m looking for is something like `range` in the `hist` function, but for the y-axis.

---

**Update:**

```
    plotNumber = 1
for i in xrange(4):
    pylab.subplot(2, 2, plotNumber)
    pylab.hist(myData[i], bins = 20, range=(0,400))
    pylab.title('Some Title')
    pylab.xlabel('X')
    pylab.ylabel('Y')
    plotNumber += 1
pylab.show()
```

But when I include

```
pylab.axis([0,400,0,300])
```

All the y-values correspond to 0 (the histogram is flat).

Comment: I tried your example (using random data, but the same histogram parameters) and was able to set both x and y limits using xlim() and ylim(). What's the text of the error you get?

Comment: @DerekJones I don't get an error, I just get a histogram that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is given here: [setting y-axis limit in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777861/setting-y-axis-limit-in-matplotlib)

```
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
axes.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
```

For me this works for histogram subplots.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to set ticks on the y-axis every n values, you can use:

```
pylab.yticks(range(min, max, n))
```

I am using Python 2.7.