# Get the limits of matplotlib interactive plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, interactive

In my plotting application written in Python, I use matplotlib (with TkAgg backend) to draw some data.

This plot is interactive, so the user can drag/zoom the plot region. However, sometimes the application needs to clear the curves and plot them anew - and as a result, the plot rescales to the extent of the curves.

It would be better to keep the user-defined limits. However, calling e.g. `ax.get_xlim()` returns the limits that were originally set by `ax.set_xlim(...)`, not the current limits that the user has changed by their mouse.

I tried hard to find the solution in the documentation and examples, yet still I could not resolve this simple task: How to get the current limits of interactive matplotlib plot?

Comment: If you are interested, I can strip my program of ca. 800 lines of code and provide also a minimum working example of what I need. But I believe it is quite clear.

Comment: The examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490436/matplotlib-finding-out-xlim-and-ylim-after-zoom) don't work?

Comment: @berna1111 Will check this out.

Comment: You can also try to [turn off auto-scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629830/how-to-turn-off-autoscaling-in-matplotlib-pyplot): `plt.autoscale(False)`

Comment: There must be some serious trouble in my codes, I guess. None of these two hints makes any change in my program. Matplotlib is great for very complex plotting, but some trivial settings can take hours of trial and error...

Comment: Try and replicate the situation in a simpler example, you might catch what's amiss. Are you sure you are asking for the limits of the correct `ax` (you are not using that name for anything else)? Place the `plt.autoscale(False)` right after the `import matplotlib.pyplot/pylab as plt`, or try `ax.autoscale(False)` after creating the axis.

Comment: I am somewhat tight on time now, so I will make further testing later. Currently, I have established that directly in the resize event handler, `axes.get_xlim()` gives the correct value, but in the plotting routine, the `ax.get_xlim()` is again wrong. This appears really weird to me, but I could fix it for now. I am still puzzled why it behaves this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137801/discussion-between-berna1111-and-dominecf).