# how I can plot the line graph as shown in the image

Tags: python, pandas, plot, line-plot

I have two columns one is date column and the other column is the cumulative data column. I want to show the graph as shown in the desired output. But I want to set the range of the Y-axis column in the line graph. value [0,1].

[image: This is the output of my code]

```
ax = plt.gca()

df_selected.plot(kind='line',marker='o',x='biweek_send_date',y='sn_fuel_injector_4_1',ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='blue')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')
plt.title("Accuracy month wise of 2017")
plt.ylabel('Accuracy Rate')
plt.xlabel('Summer-Autumn-Months')
plt.show()
```

The expected output is:

[image: I want to plot graph like this]

Comment: As for setting the bounds of the y-axis, are you perhaps looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777861/setting-y-axis-limit-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: @JST99 I have to try to set the column value range 0 to 1. In my dataset column, it has lot of data for same date. I don't understand how I show it Like the expected output. My code output show me lot of data points for the same date.