# set y axis to start from 0 in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple bar chart, which looks like:

[image]

The code that produced it is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([['c++','php'],
     [3,9]])
y_pos = np.arange(len(a[0]))
labels = np.arange(1,11,1)
objects = a[1]
ax = plt.bar(a[0], a[1], align='center', alpha=1)
plt.xticks(y_pos, a[0])
plt.ylabel('usage')
plt.title('Programming Languange Usage')

plt.show()
```

O made this bar chart, using `matplotlib`, the data is being taken from a `2x2 matrix`, the problem is, the `yaxis` start from 3 and stop at 9, I want it to start from 0 and stop at 10. The problem that causing this is because I set the `yticks` from the `matrix` it self, thus it gave me this number.

Thee question is, how do I set the `yticks` to start from 0 and stop at 10 ?, I tried using `np.arange()` , and `pyplot.yticks`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting y-axis limit in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777861/setting-y-axis-limit-in-matplotlib)

Comment: no, by using `set_ylim` it just gave me 2 `yaxis`

Comment: there is not only one answer in that question

Comment: @luigigi That answers didnt work beacuse the array was of type `dtype='<U3'`, see my answer

Comment: You can convert the y values as you're plotting: `bars = plt.bar(a[0], a[1].astype(int))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `a` from `numpy` array to list of list will solve the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = [['c++','php'],
     [3,9]]
y_pos = np.arange(len(a[0]))
labels = np.arange(1,11,1)
objects = a[1]
bars = plt.bar(a[0], a[1], align='center', alpha=1)
plt.xticks(y_pos, a[0])
plt.ylabel('usage')
plt.title('Programming Languange Usage')

plt.show()
```

This will give the following:

[image]

The problem is that the type of the values in the array is `dtype='<U3'` meaning that it will plot a char value in the y axis.

You can always separate the array to the x labels and y values and use `numpy`.