# Scaling down a plot when using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I've been trying to plot a graph of Epoch vs Accuracy and val_accuracy from a train log I have generated. Whenever I try to plot it, the y-axis starts from 0.93 rather than it being in 0, 0.1 ,0.2... intervals. I'm new at using matplotlib or any plot function.

Here's the code for it:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

acc = pd.read_csv("train_log", sep = ',')

acc.plot("epoch", ["accuracy","val_accuracy"])
plt.savefig('acc' , dpi = 300)
```

I'm open to suggestion in complete different ways to do this.
Picture of plot :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgg0W.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting y-axis limit in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777861/setting-y-axis-limit-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been discussed [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777861/setting-y-axis-limit-in-matplotlib) There are a couple of different ways you can do this (using `plt.ylim()` or making a new variable like `axes` and then `axes.set_ylim()`), but the easiest is to use the `set_ylim` function as it gives you heaps of other handles to manipulate the plot. You can also handle the `x` axis values using the `set_xlim` function.

You can use the `set_ylim([ymin, ymax])` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,5)
y = np.arange(5,10)
axes = plt.gca()
axes.plot(x,y)
axes.set_ylim([0,10])
```

[image]

You can use the `plt.ylim()` like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,5)
y = np.arange(5,10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ylim([0,10])
```

This will produce the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the lower/bottom limit using ylim().
For details please refer:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html

Comment: This helped me, I'd like to upvote but don't have enough reputation. Thanks again