# How to show bigger the distance between two curves in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, spline

I wrote a code to plot two curves passing through two data sets. However, after plotting, it turned out that the distance is little. Therefore, I need to rescale the y-axis to show the distance clearly in the resulting figure. But I do not know how to do this.

The code is this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# Dataset
x = np.array([41/300,46/300,65/300,69/300,73/300,75/300,81/300,87/300,101/300,116/300,122/300,128/300])
y = np.array([186.492147/100,185.1351/100,181.1801/100,179.8990/100,178.0152/100,177.4235/100,176.8346/100,175.6332/100,173.8296/100 ,
              172.0626/100,171.4815/100, 170.9044/100])
 
X_Y_Spline = make_interp_spline(x, y)



X_ = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 500)
Y_ = X_Y_Spline(X_)

u = np.array([50/300,54/300,66/300,72/300,74/300,75/300,101/300,102/300,110/300,113/300,116/300,118/300,130/300])
v = np.array([183.724636117654/100,182.900/100,180.886911726436/100,178.160318153782/100,177.626286563695/100,
              177.403672688541/100,173.695126295789/100,173.666369492423/100,172.52494955916/100,172.273125402593/100,
             171.888413653382/100, 171.633213514319/100,170.670417094034/100])

uv_Spline = make_interp_spline(u,v)
U_ = np.linspace(u.min(), u.max(), 500)
V_ = uv_Spline(U_)


plt.plot(U_, V_,linewidth=0.5)
plt.plot(X_, Y_,linewidth=0.5)

plt.show()
```

I want to show clearly that these two curves have enough distances between themselves somewhere in their domain. Is there any way to do so? I do not know whether to rescale the y-axis? If so, what is is syntax?

I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: You are looking for [`ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3777861/8881141)

Comment: Also when comparing two data sets it is helpful to plt the difference in a separate subplot.

Comment: @Mr.T   Thanj you so much. It helped me a lot.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Even if the curves are resulted from spline?