# change y scale of a plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using matplotlib to build plots, the problem is that given the two images I need the scale in the y-axis to be the same as I have in the MATRIX SIZE 500 plot for both plots.
the MATRIX SIZE 20000 plot has a different scale and I need to change it. How can a different scale be set?

[image]

[image]

Comment: with ```ylim``` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting y-axis limit in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777861/setting-y-axis-limit-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `plt.ylim()` function to limit the `y` axis of your plots of matplotlib. Also, you can perform the same operation on the `x` axis with `plt.xlim()` function.

Here you have a code example:

```
a, b = -10, 10
plt.ylim((a, b)) #Where a, b represent the bottom and top limits for your plot

#Another notation
plt.ylim(bottom=a)
plt.ylim(top=b)
```

Comment: this solution does not solve the problem. I just wanna get rid of "1e7" on the plot of the first image and get the full number of the ticks on y-axes. I want to get 6000000 not 6 for example