# Shift plot to the left into negative timescale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've tried to shift the plot to start from -80ms but failed. The desired output would be having the plot iniate from -80ms. I tried with set_xlim but I believe it's only valid within the given range of the dataset. Please let me know what to modify to achieve the desired output. Thanks  in advance!

First attempt:

[image: First attempt]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('time (10ms)')
ax.set_ylabel('average firing rate in 10ms')
ax.set_title('Raw PSTH data with the first three conditions of the first neuron')
# ax.legend(title='Fruit color')
# ax.set_xlim(-80, 50)

ax.plot(X[0,0,:])
ax.plot(X[0,1,:])
ax.plot(X[0,2,:])
# plt.xlabel('time(ms)')
ax.set_xlim(xmin=0)
# get_colors(xs, ys, alt_colors=False)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Second Attempt with ax.set_xlim:

[image: Second Attempt with ax.set_xlim]

Hi there, I've tried to shift the plot to start from -80ms but failed. The desired output would be having the plot iniate from -80ms. I tried with set_xlim but I believe it's only valid within the given range of the dataset. Please let me know what to modify to achieve the desired output. Thanks  in advance!

Comment: Change `ax.set_xlim(xmin=0)` to `ax.set_xlim(xmin=-80)`

Comment: As per [How to set the axis limits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3777861/7758804)

Comment: Do any of your data points have x < 0?

Comment: Hi Tim, the dataset doesn't have values below x<0, all defined from time 0s. but it is defined in the text that the iniation of the motion would be the time when x = 0. and any other values collected are in the negative region.

Comment: Hi Trenton, I belive that function is only valid when the dataset is in the range of (-80,50), however the recording initiates at time = 0s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the x axis values when you plot the lines:

```py
ax.plot(np.arange(X[0,0,:].shape[-1]) - 80, X[0,0,:])
```

Therefore, your code would look like:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('time (10ms)')
ax.set_ylabel('average firing rate in 10ms')
ax.set_title('Raw PSTH data with the first three conditions of the first neuron')

ax.plot(np.arange(X[0,0,:].shape[-1]) - 80, X[0,0,:])
ax.plot(np.arange(X[0,1,:].shape[-1]) - 80, X[0,1,:])
ax.plot(np.arange(X[0,2,:].shape[-1]) - 80, X[0,2,:])

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi OSainz, many thanks, this method works. I thought there might be a cleverer method to change the axis but I'm fine with shifting it directly.