# Bar Graph not showing 0

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, yaxis

The y-axis of my bar graph isn't starting from 0.
It is taking the minimum of the three values to be displayed as the starting point.
I want it to go from zero to fifteen

```
data = {'Average Time of 1st Instance':average_value1, 'Average Time of 2nd Instance':average_value2, 'Average Time of 3rd Instance':average_value3}  
instances = list(data.keys())  
times = list(data.values())  
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
plt.bar(instances, times, color ='blue', width = 0.4)
plt.xlabel('Instance of ++HSS')
plt.ylabel('Time in Seconds')
plt.title('Time Taken to run the Three Instances of ++HSS')`  
plt.show()
```

This is the graph I'm getting:

[image: Graph]

Setting the y axis limits using
`plt.ylim(0, 15)`
is also not working

Data:
`average_value1 = 8.88`
`average_value2 = 11.86`
`average_value3 = 11.36`

Comment: seems like times and instances are the wrong way around in the function call, notice the weird labels on th y axes

Comment: please post the contents of the variables `instances` and `times`

Comment: Instances are just 1, 2 and 3 and the times have been updated above

Comment: Some of the options here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3777861/8350330 might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `average_value` values are strings rather than numbers. If you change the line:

```
times = list(data.values())
```

to instead be:

```
times = [float(d) for d in data.values()]
```

to explicitly convert the values to floating point numbers you should get what you expect.

Alternatively, convert them when you create the dictionary, i.e.,

```
data = {
    'Average Time of 1st Instance': float(average_value1),
    'Average Time of 2nd Instance': float(average_value2),
    'Average Time of 3rd Instance': float(average_value3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add also the ticks values? Something on the line of this:

```
    yticks = np.linspace(0,15,3) 
    plt.yticks(yticks, yticks)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [How to set the axis limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777861/how-to-set-the-axis-limits) . In particular I would use

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
```