# Pyplot/Subplot APIs Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making something using Matplotlib where I have multiple subplots on a figure. It seems to me like the subplot API is limited compared to the PyPlot API: for example, I can't seem to make custom axes labels in my subplot although it is possible using PyPlot.

My question is: Is there a richer subplot API besides the tiny one on the PyPlot page (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html), and/or is there a way to get the full functionality of a PyPlot on a subplot?

Basically, what is a `subplot`? I can't find it in the documentation. Even more generally, when should I use a `figure` vs an `axis` vs a `subplot`? They all seem to do essentially the same thing.

Consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
```

Then `ax` is an `axis`? Can I use the `pyplot` API to customize `ax`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A `figure` can contain many `axes` and the `subplot` methods are just a convenient way of creating the `axes`. I'm not sure what you're asking, but maybe clearing out the terminology already helps you to understand the matplotlib documentation.

Comment: I put an example in my question. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation clearly states that an `matplotlib.axes.Axes` instance will be returned. This instance has all kinds of methods to set properties, like `set_xlabel`. I recommend using `ipython --pylab` to get an interactive session of python with matplotlib to play around with these instances and discover their behavior.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849483/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-plot-matplotlib-or-pylab/16849816#16849816

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858192/how-to-set-xlim-and-ylim-for-a-subplot-in-matplotlib/15858264#15858264

Comment: You have it backwards, `pyplot` is the limited api, talking directly to the `Axes` objects is the full api.  `pyplot` is for the most parj just a very thin wrapper around the OO api.

Answer (score 0):

While i suggest that use the axes methods, there is the plt.sca function (set current axes).
So

```
plt.sca(ax)
```

does what you want, i think.