# Setting active subplot using axes object in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The object oriented matplotlib subplots interface is nice, but I am having difficulty using it when calling a function that contains lines like `plt.plot(x, y`). These functions work with `plt.subplot()` easily, but is it possible to set the active subplot with a given axes object? Specifically I want something like the following to plot into two seperate subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0 ,1, 2]
y= [0 ,1 2]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1)

plt.some_function_to_set_active_subplot(axs[0])
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.some_function_to_set_active_subplot(axs[1])
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Does any such function `some_function_to_set_active_subplot` exist?

*Edit:* I specifically cannot use ax.plot, or anything like that. I am basically asking about how to mix the object oriented interface with the matlab style interface.

*Edit 2:* I don't want to use `plt.subplot` either. I want to use OO interface for setting up subplots, and matlab-style for the actual plotting.

Comment: What about `axs[0].plot(...)` ?

Comment: I can't use that. suppose I have some function `plotter(x, y)` that contains a `plt.plot` call deep inside, and I can't change the function to call `axs[0].plot()`.

Comment: You might want to change that function to take an additional argument `ax` then.

Comment: agreed, I tend to do this with the code I write personally, but sometimes refactoring is not possible, or desired.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858192/how-to-set-xlim-and-ylim-for-a-subplot-in-matplotlib/15858264#15858264 <- related

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254379/how-can-i-attach-a-pyplot-function-to-a-figure-instance/14261698#14261698 <- related

Comment: In general thought you _don't_ want to do this, just use the OO interface.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `plt.axes` to set the current active axes. From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes): "axes(h) where h is an axes instance makes h the current axis."

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0 ,1, 2]
y = [10 ,20, 30]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1)

plt.axes(axs[0])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axes(axs[1])
plt.plot(y,x)
plt.show()
```

Comment: there is also `plt.sca(ax)`

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell! Is plt.sca(ax) better than plt.axes(ax)? (If you have to use either.)

Comment: Thanks! this is great. `plt.gca` -- `plt.sca`, duh

Comment: `plt.sca` is better as is it just sets the current axes.  If you use `plt.axes` does some logic to check if it needs to create an axes.  If you look at the source `plt.axes` uses `plt.gcf().sca(ax)`.

Answer (score 10):

The method [`plt.axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axes.html) is deprecated for this use. Use [`plt.sca`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.sca.html) instead. Following the example above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0 ,1, 2]
y = [10 ,20, 30]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1)

plt.sca(axs[0])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.sca(axs[1])
plt.plot(y,x)
plt.show()
```