# matplotlib nan as starting values or ending values

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, nan

I want to plot a fixed date intervall, for example for last weeks data. Some of the data points (y values) might be missing because of some errors or downtime of a logger. I set these values to None or nan (same thing). This works perfectely as long as the None values are somewhere in the middle of the dataset and the expected gaps are there. However when the data is missing in the beginning or end, those values are truncated by matplotlib. Is it possible to make matplotlib not truncate my data?

i.e the y values [None,None,None,None,456,None,None,456,None,None] gives the following results:
[image]
i.e the first None results are removed. The best solution found so far is by adding 0 values at the start and end which shows all data: [0,None,None,None,456,None,None,456,None,0]
[image]

It would be lovely with a proper solution insted of adding 0 as the first and last value. I am plotting with plot_date.

Comment: What you're looking for is [how to set xlim ... in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858192/how-to-set-xlim-and-ylim-for-a-subplot-in-matplotlib).

Comment: Yes, that solved it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All credit goes to will but since he did not respond with an answer I will. The solution is really easy, just set the limits of the plot.

```
plt.xlim(min_value,max_value)
```

The answer is found in [how to set xlim in matpltlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858192/how-to-set-xlim-and-ylim-for-a-subplot-in-matplotlib)