# Unable to control scale of second y-axis on df.plot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, multiple-axes

I am trying to plot 3 series with 2 on the left y-axis and 1 on the right using `secondary_y`, but it’s not clear to me how to define the right y-axis scale as I did on the left with `ylim=()`.

I have seen this post: [Interact directly with axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762181/adding-a-y-axis-label-to-secondary-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

… but once I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3))

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(df.index,df.iloc[:,[0,2]])
ax2.plot(df.index, df.iloc[:,2])
```

`plt.show()` doesn't produce anything at all. I am using:

- Spyder 2.3.5.2
- python: 3.4.3.final.0
- python-bits: 64
- OS: Windows
- OS-release: 7
- pandas: 0.16.2
- numpy: 1.9.2
- scipy: 0.15.1
- matplotlib: 1.4.3

[image: What I get for results]

I found these links helpful:

[tcaswell, working directly with axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858192/how-to-set-xlim-and-ylim-for-a-subplot-in-matplotlib)

[matplotlib.axes documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html)

Comment: note - I just updated to pandas 0.17.1, matplotlib 1.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`set_ylim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim) on the appropriate ax.

For example:

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(bottom=-10, top=10)
```

Also, reviewing your code, it appears that you are specifying your `iloc` columns incorrectly.  Try:

```
ax1.plot(df.index, df.iloc[:, :2])  # Columns 0 and 1.
ax2.plot(df.index, df.iloc[:, 2])   # Column 2.
```

Comment: hi Alexander - I see the problem with my iloc columns, sorry for that. Can you think of a reason why there would be no repsonse at all? neither plt.show() nor plt.show(ax2) produces any plot.

Comment: Per your edit, you have the graphic.  When you say 'no response', what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: good point, poorly worded. i was not able to get a result working only in the console. your corrections to my syntax helped me get back on track. i still have some bad looking plots because the grid lines for the two y axis ticks are off. i will add some other useful links above. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3))
print (df)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(df.index,df.iloc[:,[0,2]])
ax2.plot(df.index, df.iloc[:,2])

plt.show()
```

Comment: hi toasteez - thanks for responding. I pasted in an image of what I had written above. I must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: I'm running Anaconda 3.5, from Pycharm nothing displays for me either but if I run from console it plots fine.

Comment: I cannot get anything from the iPython console in Anaconda/spyder

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without directly calling ax.twinx():

```
#Plot the first series on the LH y-axis
ax1 = df.plot('x_column','y1_column')

#Add the second series plot, and grab the RH axis
ax2 = df.plot('x_column','y2_column',ax=ax1)
ax2.set_ylim(0,10)
```

Note: Only tested in Pandas 19.2