# Matplotlib: how to locate ticks and showing min and max of data

Tags: python, matplotlib

Good day,

I would like to dynamically locate my ticks and showing the min and max of the data (which is varying, thus I really can't harcode the conditions). I'm trying to use matplotlib.ticker functions and the best that I can find is `MaxNLocator()`.. but unfortunately, it does not consider the limits of my dataset.

What would be the best approach to my problem?

Thanks!

pseudocode as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator


data1 = range(5)
ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(data1)

data2 = range(63)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.plot(data2)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

plt.show()
```

and the output is:

[image: Matplotlib ticks and data limits]

Comment: plt.xlim( (xmin, xmax) )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858192/how-to-set-xlim-and-ylim-for-a-subplot-in-matplotlib

Comment: @Silencer I don't think that's quite what the OP is asking. I think they want ticks located from 0 to 63 (in this case) but in the example the ticks go from 0 to 64. Changing the limits in this example doesn't change the tick location

Comment: Nope, it just removes the trailing ticks on the side, but still does not reflect the limits on the ticks. Thanks tho.

Comment: I don't understand with the downvote. If you have concerns, please address it rather than clicking the downvote. Let's be constructive :/

Comment: A band-aid solution that I did is that I'll `xticks = get_xticks()`, `xticks[-2] = vmax`. It's not as robust but that'll do. I do hope there's other better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about *best* approach, but one possible way to do this would be to create a list of numbers between your minimum and maximum using `numpy.linspace(start, stop, num)`. The third argument passed to this lets you control the number of points generated. You can then round these numbers using a list comprehension, and then set the ticks using `ax.set_xticks()`.

**Note:** This will produce unevenly distributed ticks in *some* cases, which may be unavoidable in your case

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np

data1 = range(5)
ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(data1)

data2 = range(63)  # max of this is 62, not 63 as in the question
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.plot(data2)

ticks1 = np.linspace(min(data1),max(data1),5)
ticks2 = np.linspace(min(data2),max(data2),5)

int_ticks1 = [round(i) for i in ticks1]
int_ticks2 = [round(i) for i in ticks2]

ax1.set_xticks(int_ticks1)
ax2.set_xticks(int_ticks2)

plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

**Update:** This will give a *maximum* numbers of ticks of 5, however if the data goes from say `range(3)` then the number of ticks will be less. I have updates the creating of `int_ticks1` and `int_ticks2` so that only unique values will be used to avoid repeated plotting of certain ticks if the range is small

Using the following data

```
data1 = range(3)
data2 = range(3063)

# below removes any duplicate ticks
int_ticks1 = list(set([int(round(i)) for i in ticks1]))
int_ticks2 = list(set([int(round(i)) for i in ticks2]))
```

This produces the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but I really can't hardcode the conditions (5 ticks for data1 and 10 ticks for data 2) as the data is really varying. The plotting is enclosed in a function, so every data uses the same plotting function.

Comment: Do you want a constant number of ticks all the time then?

Comment: No, the data is sometimes only less than 5, but sometimes also larger than 50. So number of ticks couldn't be constant.

Comment: @c4mm11 So putting for example 5 in `np.linspace` creates a maximum of 5 ticks. If your data range is small then it will create less than 5 (providing the duplicate ticks are removed). I have updated my answer with a few additions.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the `set`. The solution works but produces uneven ticks. Sadly, the visual is very important in my output.

I'm really grateful for the effort.

Comment: You won't be able to get evenly spaced ticks from 0 - 62 that include 0 and 62...