# Show specific range in graphic

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm just starting with matplotlib. For example, having the following code:

```
import pylab

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

pylab.plot(x, y)
pylab.axhline(0, color="black")
pylab.axvline(0, color="black")

pylab.show()
```

[image]

Shows from `0` to `8` (Y) and `0` to `7` (X). Is there anyway to specify the range of the values showed in the axes? For example, from `-5` to `3` and from `-5` to `3`. It doesn't matter if the function line is out of that range.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, Matplotlib, subplot: How to set the axis range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849286/python-matplotlib-subplot-how-to-set-the-axis-range)

Comment: Disagree about the duplicate, that question knew they should use `xlim`, but were getting messed up by order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `pylab.{x|y}lim(min, max)`:

```
import pylab

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

pylab.plot(x, y)
pylab.axhline(0, color="black")
pylab.axvline(0, color="black")

# Here we go:
pylab.xlim(-5, 3)
pylab.ylim(-5, 3)

pylab.show()
```

Edit: I agree with  @tcaswell. You should use the pyplot package instead:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axhline(0, color="black")
plt.axvline(0, color="black")

plt.xlim(-5, 3)
plt.ylim(-5, 3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Don't use `pylab`, use `pyplot` instead (pylab is just a cluttered namespace).  And you _should_ be using the OO interface anyway.

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks for the tip! I'm just starting with matplotlib :-)