# Convert 24 hour format to 12 hour in pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

**Dataset:**

```
                  starttime   User Type
0         7/1/2015 00:00:03  Subscriber
1         7/1/2015 00:00:06  Subscriber
2         7/1/2015 00:00:17  Subscriber
3         7/1/2015 00:00:23  Subscriber
4         7/1/2015 00:00:44  Subscriber
5         7/1/2015 00:01:00  Subscriber
6         7/1/2015 00:01:03  Subscriber
7         7/1/2015 00:01:06  Subscriber
8         7/1/2015 00:01:25    Customer
9         7/1/2015 00:01:41  Subscriber
10        7/1/2015 00:01:50    Customer
11        7/1/2015 00:01:58  Subscriber
12        7/1/2015 00:02:06  Subscriber
13        7/1/2015 00:02:07  Subscriber
14        7/1/2015 00:02:26  Subscriber
15        7/1/2015 00:02:26  Subscriber
16        7/1/2015 00:02:35  Subscriber
17        7/1/2015 00:02:43    Customer
18        7/1/2015 00:02:47    Customer
19        7/1/2015 00:02:47  Subscriber
20        7/1/2015 00:03:05  Subscriber
21        7/1/2015 00:03:16    Customer
22        7/1/2015 00:03:27  Subscriber
23        7/1/2015 00:03:34  Subscriber
24        7/1/2015 00:03:48  Subscriber
25        7/1/2015 00:03:56  Subscriber
26        7/1/2015 00:03:57  Subscriber
27        7/1/2015 00:03:58    Customer
28        7/1/2015 00:04:03  Subscriber
29        7/1/2015 00:04:17  Subscriber
...                     ...         ...
1085646  7/31/2015 23:57:25  Subscriber
1085647  7/31/2015 23:57:29    Customer
1085648  7/31/2015 23:57:32  Subscriber
1085649  7/31/2015 23:57:33  Subscriber
1085650  7/31/2015 23:57:44  Subscriber
1085651  7/31/2015 23:57:54  Subscriber
1085652  7/31/2015 23:58:03  Subscriber
1085653  7/31/2015 23:58:08  Subscriber
1085654  7/31/2015 23:58:12    Customer
1085655  7/31/2015 23:58:15  Subscriber
1085656  7/31/2015 23:58:18    Customer
1085657  7/31/2015 23:58:24  Subscriber
1085658  7/31/2015 23:58:27  Subscriber
1085659  7/31/2015 23:58:42  Subscriber
1085660  7/31/2015 23:58:43  Subscriber
1085661  7/31/2015 23:58:51    Customer
1085662  7/31/2015 23:58:53  Subscriber
1085663  7/31/2015 23:58:58  Subscriber
1085664  7/31/2015 23:59:04  Subscriber
1085665  7/31/2015 23:59:10  Subscriber
1085666  7/31/2015 23:59:24  Subscriber
1085667  7/31/2015 23:59:23    Customer
1085668  7/31/2015 23:59:24  Subscriber
1085669  7/31/2015 23:59:24  Subscriber
1085670  7/31/2015 23:59:38  Subscriber
1085671  7/31/2015 23:59:40  Subscriber
1085672  7/31/2015 23:59:41  Subscriber
1085673  7/31/2015 23:59:42    Customer
1085674  7/31/2015 23:59:56  Subscriber
1085675  7/31/2015 23:59:59  Subscriber
```

**Question**

Create a pandas DataFrame with the number of rides by User Type for each hour of the day. Use starttime to determine each ride's hour.

**Output**

```
User    Customer    Subscriber
Type
start
time    
  0     2464    9259
  1     1377    5042
  2     871     2882
  3     597     1755
  4     373     1691
  5     444     5726
  6     1098    22982
  7     2094    45393
  8     4159    78258
  9     5973    61062
  10    8330    36497
  11    11396   35765
  12    13039   41474
  13    13510   42711
  14    14497   42537
  15    15944   46570
  16    15644   58096
  17    16203   90153
  18    14812   92357
  19    12309   67654
  20    9237    45756
  21    6414    31312
  22    5503    24220
  23    4074    16162
```

which is correct and 
**Graph is**
[image]

**instead of**

[image]

Where time is in 12-hour format

**Code**

```
def a9(rides):
    rides['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(rides['starttime'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df = pd.crosstab(rides.starttime.dt.hour, rides['User Type'])
    return df
```

**How can I display time on x-axis in 12-hour format instead of 24 hours.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use[`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) - http://strftime.org/, but for correct ordering need ordered categorical:

```
rides['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(rides['starttime'], infer_datetime_format=True)
cats = ['12 AM', '01 AM', '02 AM', '03 AM', '04 AM', '05 AM', '06 AM', '07 AM', '08 AM', '09 AM', '10 AM', '11 AM', '12 PM', '01 PM', '02 PM', '03 PM', '04 PM', '05 PM', '06 PM', '07 PM', '08 PM', '09 PM', '10 PM', '11 PM']
dates = pd.Categorical(rides.starttime.dt.strftime('%I %p'), categories=cats, ordered=True)
df = pd.crosstab(dates, rides['User Type'])
print (df)
User Type  Customer  Subscriber
row_0                          
12 AM             6          24
01 AM             0           0
02 AM             0           0
03 AM             0           0
04 AM             0           0
05 AM             0           0
06 AM             0           0
07 AM             0           0
08 AM             0           0
09 AM             0           0
10 AM             0           0
11 AM             0           0
12 PM             0           0
01 PM             0           0
02 PM             0           0
03 PM             0           0
04 PM             0           0
05 PM             0           0
06 PM             0           0
07 PM             0           0
08 PM             0           0
09 PM             0           0
10 PM             0           0
11 PM             6          24
```

List for categories is generated from:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 00:00:00', periods=24, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'starttime': rng})  
cats = df.starttime.dt.strftime('%I %p').tolist()
```

Comment: Yep, that should definately work. OP could also have a look at: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/api/date.html

Comment: it works but why time is in like `01 AM 01 PM 02 AM 02 PM ...` like this

Comment: frequency on X-Axis is very low, can we increase it? Like There is a big gap between 12 AM and then direct 5 AM. How can we display all time on X-Axis

Comment: It is more question for some matplotlib expert, not for me... But maybe need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849286/python-matplotlib-subplot-how-to-set-the-axis-range)