# How to set extent for matplotlib plt.show()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making some prototype which displays diagrams like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
... 

plt.plot(xs, ys)
...
plt.show()
```

Getting window like

[image]

and now want to correct programmatically extent of the diagram to be open. To get something like

[image]

right after start. How to do this?

Comment: you mean [`xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) and  [`ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html)? see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849286/python-matplotlib-subplot-how-to-set-the-axis-range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the upper and lower bounds for the x-axis and y-axis:

`plt.xlim([0,45])`

`plt.ylim([0.00025,0.00200])`

Use these after `plt.plot()` and before `plt.show()`

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you very much! :)