# How can I set a default zoom in a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following code...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(seed=2021)

x = np.arange(0, 200)
y = np.random.randint(1, 10, 200)

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

...that generates this chart:

[image]

What I need is when the code start, the chart zooms by default to the last 25 records.

[image]

I do not want to limit the data. I want the 200 records to continue graphing, so that later I can move through the chart (with the arrow in the lower left corner) in case I want to see the historical data.

Is there a way to set a default zoom when the chart start?

Comment: how about `plt.xlim(175,  200)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, Matplotlib, subplot: How to set the axis range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849286/python-matplotlib-subplot-how-to-set-the-axis-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to hard code the left limit in `xlim`, you can read the shape of your x array and use this to plot only the last 25 samples:

`plt.xlim(left=x.shape[0]-25)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `plt.xlim(175, 200)` which sets the limit of the x axis.